# Pandas use dataframe as dictionary or lookup

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, lookup

Not winning here. Need to use a free text field passed into a dataframe to lookup a different column in a second data frame:

> ```
> df1 = pd.read_csv('Hotel_reviews.csv')
>
> ...
> user:     Review:
> Julie     'Sheets were dirty'
> Samantha  'Meal arrived cold'
> Rachel    'Cocktails were delicious'
> ]
> ...
> ```

imagine lots of data above ^

> ```
> df2 = [{'Keyword':['Sheets','Cocktails','Meal'],
> 'Department' :['Bedrooms','Restaurant','Restaurant'],
> 'Issue Type':['Beds','Drinks','Food']}]
> ```

I've tried a number of methods to arrive at this:

> ```
> df3 =
> user:     Review:                     Department:     Issue Type:
> Julie     'Sheets were dirty'         'Bedrooms'      'Beds'
> Samantha  'Meal arrived cold'         'Restaurant'    'Food'
> Rachel    'Cocktails were delicious'  'Restaurant'    'Drinks'
> ```

This is what I've tried:

## TRY1

> ```
> def find_dept(review):
>     words = review.split(' ')
>     for word in words:
>         if word.isin(df2['Keyword']):
>              return df2[df2['word'] ==word]['Department']
>
> dept = df['Review'].apply(find_dept)
> ```

## TRY2

> ```
> for dept in df2['Department']:    
>      if dept.isin(review):
>           return True
> ```

## TRY3

> ```
> review_dict = df2.to_dict('series')
> def r_dict(review):
>     return review_dict[review]
>
> dept = df['Review'].apply(r_dict)
> ```

Needless to say, I am struggling......

apologies for not exactly correct formatting, this is a made up examples and my caffeine levels are dipping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way. The idea is to convert your mapping dictionary to the format `keyword: (department, issue)`.

Then use a generator expression to find the first match, looping through your new dictionary.

Finally, split a series of tuples into 2 columns via `pd.Series.apply(pd.Series)`.

Note dictionaries are not considered to be ordered. So, for multiple matches, you should consider it chance which one gets picked. If you want to search in a particular order, use an ordered dictionary (lookup `collections.OrderedDict`).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Julie', 'Sheets were dirty'],
                   ['Samantha', 'Meal arrived cold'],
                   ['Rachel', 'Cocktails were delicious']],
                  columns=['User', 'Review'])

d = {'Keyword': ['Sheets','Cocktails','Meal'],
     'Department' : ['Bedrooms','Restaurant','Restaurant'],
     'Issue Type': ['Beds','Drinks','Food']}

d2 = {key: (dep, iss) for key, dep, iss in \
           zip(d['Keyword'], d['Department'], d['Issue Type'])}

def mapper(x):
    return d2.get(next((i for i in d2 if i in x), None))

df[['Department', 'IssueType']] = df['Review'].apply(mapper).apply(pd.Series)
```

Result:

```
       User                    Review  Department IssueType
0     Julie         Sheets were dirty    Bedrooms      Beds
1  Samantha         Meal arrived cold  Restaurant      Food
2    Rachel  Cocktails were delicious  Restaurant    Drinks
```

Comment: Absolutely spectacular. Not sure I understand it, but it works like a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: If the text has two keywords in it with different departments, will it select the first or the second department?